# Creating mysql database for Drupal

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create **Mysql** database for **Drupal** according to these instructions
"
First, you must create a new database for your **Drupal** site (here, 'databasename'
is the name of the new database):

```
mysqladmin -u username -p create databasename
```

"
I'm using **Ubuntu**.
After the command

```
$ mysqladmin -u xralf -p create ralfdb
```

it wrote this error

> mysqladmin: connect to server at
>   'localhost' failed error: 'Access
>   denied for user 'xralf'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)'

Could you help me with this problem?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The username needs to be for a username that has the right to create a new database i believe - for a fresh install - most likely root

[this should walk you through it](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-create-a-mysql-database-and-set-privileges-to-a-user)

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, you can just use [Bitnami Drupal Stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/drupal), which installs mysql and all dependencies with a simple graphical wizzard.

Or you could install [LAMPStack](http://bitnami.org/stack/lampstack), which serves as a common infrastructure, then download the Drupal Stack [module](http://bitnami.org/stack/drupal) and install it (and any other apps you find there as modules, sharing the same LAMPStack as a base. )

Comment: Thank you for interesting alternatives, but I would like to continue with what I began.